# Sort an array of items (with X/Y properties) so they are ordered left to right, top to bottom

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, algorithm, sorting

Each item in the array in on the stage, each with an x/y position. The item in the top left most position should be items[0]. X should be the primary.

[image]

Originally I was thinking along the lines of:

```
var items = [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6];

items.sort(sortMe);    

function sortMe(a, b)
{
    return (b.position[0] - a.position[0]) && (b.position[1] - a.position[1]);
}
```

But this does not yield the correct results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sort()` should return either `0` or a negative/positive number.

This sorts with `X` taking precedence:

```
function sortByPosition(a, b){
  if (a.x == b.x) return a.y - b.y;
  return a.x - b.x;
}
```

This with `Y` taking precedence (the "natural" order):

```
function sortByPosition(a, b){
  if (a.y == b.y) return a.x - b.x;
  return a.y - b.y;
}
```

Which means you just need to replace your `&&` with `||`:

```
return a.x - b.x || a.y - b.y
```

Comment: Actually `sort()` can return positive, negative or zero.  It doesn't have to be 1 or -1.

Comment: fixed it so that X takes precedence.

Comment: Could you please help me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322127/how-to-sort-geo-coordinates-from-top-most-northern-to-bottom-southern-using-java

Comment: Does not solve for spacial issues where X is smaller in some cases but Y isn't

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortMe(a, b)
{
    if( a.position[0]<b.position[0] || (a.position[0]==b.position[0] && a.position[1]<b.position[1] ) ) return 1;
    if( a.position[0]==b.position[0] && a.position[1]==b.position[1]) return 0;
    return -1;
}
```